# add stroke to UITextView's text

Tags: iphone, uitextview, quartz-graphics, core-text

Im trying to add a stroke around UITextView's text. Has anyone tried this ?

The complicated thing I can think of is to subclass UITextView and over-ride the drawText: and handle text drawing, while using a NSAttributedString.

I want the stroke to be shown around the text as the user is editing. Any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the right way is to subclass a UIView and inherit UIResponder and adopt UIKeyInput protocol [as described here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html] , and in drawRect: either use a NSAttributedString or use Quartz to add the stroke around the text.